# Cannot access image files inside my device local storage using angularjs ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am using AngularJS and Cordova, and I'm using Visual Studios 2013 to simulate the cordova application.

I have a bunch of image files inside the `ms-appdata:///local/` directory and I'm trying to show those images by using `ng-src="{{img}}"` where `$scope.img = "ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg"`

HTML

```
 <img ng-src="{{img}}" alt="" />
```

JavaScript

```
 $scope.img= "ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg";
```

When I run this code I dont even get the missing image icon thing at the top, its almost like there is no image at all.

when I change `ng-src="{{img}}"` to `src="ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg"` the image shows up no problem.

I have already tried `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg").$$unwrapTrustedValue()` as another Stack Overflow answer suggested doing.

Answer (score 1):

`$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` can help to interpolate url on `src` attribute directly, but when `ng-src` directive assigns interpolated value to `src` attribute, it is already a string, not trusted object. The information if this url was trusted is lost in `ng-src`.

`$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("...").$$unwrapTrustedValue()` doesn't make sense in this context, because it will give you the same "..." untrusted string on the output.

I believe the best thing that can be done in this case is to add a new protocol to [the white list](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist).

```
app.config(function ($compileProvider) {
  var whitelist = $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist();
  whitelist = new RegExp(whitelist.source.replace(/(ftp)/, '$1|ms-appdata'));
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(whitelist);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace ms-appdata to ftp protocol in the code?

Comment: @Gandhi It replaces `ftp` with `ftp|ms-appdata` in the middle of `^\s*((https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\/)` regexp (which may vary between Angular versions).

Comment: Specifying the following lines in the config explicitly is not working too - "$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|content|blob‌​|ms-appx|ms-appdata|x-wmapp0|unsafe|local):|data:image\//);" Any ideas?

Comment: @Gandhi Nope. Does it work in the opposite direction, when you remove `https?|` from whitelisted protocols? I would suggest to open a new question that replicates your problem and contains your own code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Was trying to help out someone on this issue. Thes issue was not with sanitization but with compileprovider getting overriden somewhere else losing all the changes. Fixed now it seems. Cheers